# Model weights not changing Keras

Tags: python, random, neural-network, keras

I am trying to create neural nets with random weights in keras. I am using set_weights() function of models, to assign random weights. However, model.predict() gives the same output on a certain input regardless of weights. The output differs every time I run the program, but it's same while a program is running. Here is the code:

ConnectFourAI.py:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from minimax2 import ConnectFour
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import itertools
import random
import time

def get_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(630, input_dim=84, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(630,kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(7, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

map = {
    'x':[1,0],
    ' ':[0,0],
    'o':[0,1]
}

model = get_model()

def get_AI_move(grid):
    global model
    inp = np.array(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([map[t] for t in np.array(grid).reshape(42)]))).reshape(1,84)
    nnout = model.predict(inp)
    # print(list(nnout[0]))
    out = np.argmax(nnout)
    while grid[0][out] != " ":
        out = np.random.randint(7)
    print("out = %d"%out)
    return out

shapes = [(w.shape) for w in model.get_weights()]

print(list(model.get_weights()[0][0][0:5]))
def score_func(x, win):
        if win == "x":
            return 10000
        elif win == " ":
            return 2000
        else:
            return x**2




if __name__=="__main__":

    for i in range(100):
        weights = [np.random.randn(*s) for s in shapes]
        # print(list(weights[0][0][0:5]))
        model.set_weights(weights)
        print(list(model.get_weights()[0][0][0:5]))
        game = ConnectFour()
        game.start_new()
        rounds = game._round
        win = game._winner
        score = score_func(rounds, win)
        print("%dth game scored %.3f"%(i+1,score))

        seed = int(time.time()* 10**6)%(2**32)+1
        np.random.seed(seed)
```

To recreate this error, you need an extra file. Everything is OK in this file, but the only call to random always gives the same value. Here is the [file](https://pastebin.com/npW0yCDL).

Comment: where are you fitting the model with training data?

Comment: I am and never will fit the neural net with any data. I want to decide weights by evolutionary algorithm. I want to create 100 random neural nets, pick the best of them, slightly modify their weights and repeat.

Comment: @SagarRohankar Do you have any idea why is this happening? Can you atleast try to recreate my problem?

Comment: Try https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html

Comment: Thanks @J.Down I will try that. Meanwhile do you have any idea why this can be happening?

Comment: tbh. I am sure why you are doing it like that..  It looks like you are training some sort of AI-player to play some game? and are interested in using GA to make it better.  GA are usually put on top of already working neural networks that knows the game, meaning their weights are already given, and not set randomly...  I am not sure I correctly understand "The output differs every time I run the program, but it's same while a program is running."

Comment: Neural net output does not change despite changing weights while the program is running, but when I stop the program and restart it, the output changes. I tried seeding it every iteration with time, but that did not help

Comment: @J.Down I forgot you were not the original commenter and I had to tag you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly was going wrong, but I came up with a work around. Apparently there was some problem in random module due to which this behaviour took place when random module is called from 2 different files. So I used one file instead of two, and got the results I expected.